# What to do with antique/older mathematics books? Throw away or something else?

Tags: reference-request

My father, who held 4 post graduate degrees and was a lifetime student, passed away recently.  He has an entire bookcase full of older mathematics books, including some on related topics such as computer science.  I already threw away some books related to computer programming, including those on languages that no one uses anymore, like APL.  But then it occurred to me that maybe someone would want some of these older books and I should not just throw them away.  Does anyone here have any suggestions as to what I should do with them?  thank you

Comment: Used book stores like Powell's or The Strand might buy them for a dollar or two per book, especially the hardcovers. There are more ideas and data along the same lines at https://bookriot.com/sell-used-books/.

Comment: You may make a donation to your father's university

Comment: Some answers are posted under [What to do with antique math books?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/9793).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do with antique math books?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9793/what-to-do-with-antique-math-books)

Comment: The following was posted in the MAA mailing list in June 2021:

"Jason Cantarella's daughter is collecting and selling used advanced math books very cheaply (almost all are \$15-\$50) in order to pay for equipment for her homeschool science experiments and engineering projects. You can find her inventory online at https://amazon.com/shops/mathbookrescuesociety. I would send Jason an email (jhc7447@uga.edu)."

Comment: Zubal Books in Cleveland (https://www.zubalbooks.com/) has something of a specialty in math books.

Comment: I did see the prior post under What to do with antique math books? but it is over 10 years old and I wasn't sure if the answers were still relevant.  Thank you to those with suggestions, I will be sending emails to Zubal, Michener-Rutledge and Jason Cantarella in hopes they may want some of these books.  It would be nice to find someone who would want them, I know my father enjoyed them.

Comment: Many less developed countries are desperate for such material.  It depends on where you are based but most national mathematical societies have a specialist section to which you could turn to with questions about the feasability and logistics of such a donation.

Comment: For 10k users: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181394/old-math-books-will-research-and-sell-most

Comment: You may try to sell them on e-Bay, if you have time. For good books you may get substantially more than 1-2 dollars.